# return value from eval

Tags: bash, exit, exit-status, eval

The bash manual states:

```
eval [arg ...]

          The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single com-
          mand.  This command is then read and executed by the shell,  and
          its  exit status is returned as the value of eval. If there are
          no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.
```

I try

```
eval `nonsense`
echo $?
```

The result is `0`.

Whereas when I execute the back-quoted command separately:

```
`nonsense`
echo $?
```

The result is `127`.

From what is written in the bash manual I would expect `eval` to return `127` when taking the back-quoted `nonsense` as argument.

How to obtain the exit status of the argument of `eval`?

Comment: `\`nonsense\`` doesn't return anything if `nonsense` doesn't exist, so there are no arguments to `eval`.

Comment: You should run `eval nonsense`, then you will get 127.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, for the specific case at hand `nonsense` comes in back-quotes,

Comment: OK, I upvoted it because it has provided some insight to the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do the following -

```
`nonsense`
echo $?
```

You basically are asking "Tell me the exit status when I try to get the output of the command nonsense" 
the answer to that is "command not found" or 127

But when you do the following

```
eval `nonsense`
echo $?
```

You are asking  "tell me the exit status of eval when I evaluate an empty string" (the output of command nonsense) which is equal to running `eval` without arguments.

`eval` has no problems in running without arguments and its exit status becomes 0

Comment: Code formatting should not be used for English prose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy .. thanks for the edit tip, made the changes accordingly

Comment: I'm confused. The OP provided context, and that is what is being responded to, but where is the answer to the actual question posited which was: "How to obtain the exit status of the argument of eval?"  I guess I need to read more carefully?

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it's more the:

```
$ `nonsense`
bash: nonsense: command not found
$ echo "$?"
127
```

That is surprising here.

We're asking `bash` to run the command that results of the split+glob operator on the stdout of `nonsense`. Since `nonsense` produces no output, it runs no command, so you may think the exit status should be 0.

But actually, when a simple command line has no argument, only assignment or redirection, the exit status is that of the last command substitution in assignment and normal words (not in redirection targets) that was run (though failure in redirections will also affect the exit status).

That's specially useful with assignments.

In:

```
output=$(grep pattern file)
status=$?
```

You can get both the output and exit status of `grep`, which you couldn't do if `$?` was otherwise the exit status of that non-command.

In:

```
output=$(cmd1) cmd2
```

That is where there are both assignment words and argument words, the exit status of `cmd1` is ignored. `$?` will contain the exit status of `cmd2`.

And, also `$output` will only be set for `cmd2` only. Exception to that is when `cmd2` is a special builtin.

`eval` is such a *special builtin*.

```
$ a=0; a=1 eval; echo "$a"
1
```

In `bash` and most modern POSIX shells.

```
a=`exit 5` eval; echo "$?"
```

or

```
eval `exit 5`; echo "$?"
```

Would output 0, as it's the result of running `eval` with no argument. But that was not the case in the Bourne shell or ksh88, where for special builtins you'd get the exit status of `exit 5` there.

In those shells, you'll also find:

```
$ a=`exit 3` set x; echo "$?"
3
```

As `set` is another special builtin.

`.` is another special builtin. In the Bourne shell and ksh88:

```
$ . /some/file `exit 4`; echo "$?"
4
```

(as long as `/some/file` doesn't run any command)

Comment: I'm confused. The OP provided context, and that is what is being responded to, but where is the answer to the actual question posited which was: "How to obtain the exit status of the argument of eval?"  I guess I need to read more carefully?

Comment: I _think_ the answer to the question would be `eval $some_string_containing_a_command; return_value=$?` - but I agree that it doesn't seem to be directly answered.